# React Native on iOS crashed while calling native module and try to present ViewController

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

When trying to present a ViewController, on native modules it's crash.

Here is the code on the native side.

```
@objc(SomethingManager)
class SomethingManager : NSObject {

@objc(doPresent)
func doPresent() {

  let vc = UIViewController()

  let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
  navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)


  let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
  rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
  rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
}
```

the crash said

```
'Application tried to present modally an active controller <UIViewController: 0x7fb09441e620>`
```

I've tried to call it on main thread, without any luck

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to present *vc*, which is already embedded in your *navigationController*. You should therefore be presenting *navigationController* and not *vc*.

```
rootViewController?.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```